# Why can't I see anything on the map?

Tags: pokemon-go

Just downloaded Pokémon Go, I caught my first Pokémon, but after that I couldn't find any more Pokémons. I can't even see anything on the map, I tried to download the game again but it didn't work...

I tried walking around, I even drove around but I couldn't find anything. When I see other people playing it doesn't look the same.

I can see the writing 'failed to detect location' and I don't know what to do...

What do I do?

Comment: I tried walking around, I even drove around and I can't find anything. When I see other people playing it it doesn't look the same.

Comment: Do you have mock locations/ developer mode on? Do you have GPS enabled? Do you have power saving enabled? Has the game been officially released in your area?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the app crashes in the background but it doesn't tell you. You can identify this by not seeing any Pokemon and [Pokestops](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Pokestops) not showing up anymore.

Try restarting your app. If you're still not seeing Pokemon then it might be because you're in a very quiet area. In that case try going to busier areas or use [incense](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Incense) to increase the number of Pokemon around you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your phone settings, selecting Developer Mode and uncheck "Allow mock locations" if it's on, this is the cause of your "failed to detect location" error, because Niantic doesn't allow fake GPS locations in order to curb cheaters.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced that doing some of the following steps does indeed help, depending on the issue, for me and my friends:

- Download an offline map of the area you're in, in the Google Maps app.

  - A restart might be required in order for it to work.
- Shut down all other applications in your phone.
- Get an app that kills processes on your phone that you don't want to use, i.e. 365 security light or other similar apps.
- Go to the application manager and clear cache + data.
- Force a shutdown on the app if that's an option and re-open it.
- Restart phone.

I've tried these steps on my own phone and on a few of my friends and they've not failed yet.

If nothing works there's a good chance that the servers are simply too busy to handle your request, but it should be affecting other users near you just as much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any grey shadows on the screen that look like it should be a pokemon there? If you have them, you have the same problem as me. The only time I can find pokemon is if I use an incense. I have walked a few kilometers without seeing any pokemon only those stupid grey shadows. I hope you find a way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old post maybe someone having a similar problem, and found this like I did, may be helped.

Just found out an issue after an update to my phone. For whatever reason, after an update with my android, it turned off "location". Swipe down and see if "location" is toggled. Close the game and open it again. Hopefully I was clear enough. If this worked for you let me and others know so we can be sure this wasn't a random fluke.

Answer (score -1):

I just had this problem, and I fixed it by simply downloading the newest update from the App Store.